# How does tensorflow contrib.layers module deal with multi-value features?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm watching the tensorflow source code of wide and deep model,[link](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/wide_and_deep)

In this tutorial provided by tensorflow, there is only one value for each feature column.
for example,in the Census Income Dataset, one instance
 `"age":37,"marital_status":"Married-civ-spouse","education": "Bachelors"` ，each feature only has one value. 
I want to know if these functions such as`tf.contrib.layers.embedding_column、tf.contrib.layers.sparse_column_with_keys` and so on ,can deal with a feature is more than one value. such as one feature like `"personal_hobby":"'basketball','shopping','reading'"`

Comment: You just have to map the unstructured column to a structured one and concatenate it with the already existing structured data. This is a broad question and is hard to answer with a specific example. Some code that you have tried would help us augment it further

Comment: I applied WD model on my own data, but in raw data some features have multiple variable-length values,like person A has feature `"personal_hobby":"'basketball','shopping','reading'"`Person B has feature `"personal_hobby": 'shopping','swimming'"`. I deal with this feature `tf.contrib.layers.sparse_column_with_hash_bucket(column_name=personal_hobby, hash_bucket_size=30)` .However, I don‘’t know if this function treats the input `"'basketball','shopping','reading'"`  as a string, or split it to three part,`"basketball","shopping" and "reading"`. thanks!@VivekKalyanarangan